# Fast multiline regex find/replace of \r and \n

Tags: python, regex, command-line, sed, grep

I’m working with large text datasets, size of about 1 GB (the smallest file has about 2 million lines). Each line is supposed to be split into a number of columns. I say *supposed* because there are exceptions; while the normal lines end with `\r\n`, a good number of them are incorrectly divided onto 2 to 3 lines.

Given that there are 10 columns, each line is supposed to have the following format:

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | ... | col_10\r\n
```

The exceptions have this format:

```
1.  col_1 | col_2 | col_3 ...\n
    ... | col_10\r\n

2.  col_1 | col_2 | col_3 ...\n
    ... | col_10\n
    \r\n
```

What would be the fastest way to correct these exceptions? I did a simple find/replace in a text editor (TextMate, on Mac) on a sample of 1000 lines using the regular expression `(^[^\r\n]*)\n` (replacing with `$1`), and it works perfectly. But the text editor apparently cannot handle the big files (>= 2 million lines). Can those be done with `sed` or `grep` (or in some other command-line tool, or even in Python) using equivalent regular expressions, and how?

Comment: Your problem seems very familiar to me! What I did in my case was that I used a split (I work with Tcl though) and counted the number of elements obtained, then added the two lines (or more) if I get less elements, into a new file. I'm not sure how to do it in python yet, but that's the logic I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach:

```
perl -pe 's/(^[^\r\n]*)\n/\1/' input > output
```

Or, a negative lookbehind:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n//' input > output
```

Or, remove all `\n` and replace each `\r` with `\r\n`:

```
perl -pe 's/\n//; s/\r/\r\n/' input > output
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not awk? :

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="\r\n"; FS="\n"; OFS=" "; ORS="\r\n";} {print $1,$2}' input
```

Or tr + sed:

```
cat input | tr '\n' ' ' | tr '\r' '\n' | sed 's/^ \(.*\)/\1\r/g'
```

Comment: This doesn’t look right. The `awk` command seems to just delete the “trailing” parts, and although the `cat` command does that correctly, it adds extra `r`-characters to the end of each line. Anyway, I accepted the other answer; it does exactly what I want, and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

no fancy `regex` needed - just the 5 `awk` built in variables suffices :

```
 awk 'BEGIN { ORS=RS="\r"(FS="\n"(OFS=_)) } ++NF'
```